# Custom UIView is being unwrapped as nil in View Controller

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to add a custom UIView to a view controller. I have done this before and had no issues so I'm very confused here.

I have configured file owners correctly, have all required init methods, etc set up for the custom view. Nothing seems out of place to me and everything configured exactly as before.

When I run the code, neither of the custom views init methods are called (placed breakpoints on both). When I add the custom view as an IBOutlet into my view controller, I get an error saying:

"Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value".

This comes from a line in my viewcontroller attempting to change a colour of the custom view. I assume because the view hasn't been initialised so it returns nil.

So any ideas on why this custom view isn't being initialised?

ViewController:

```
class ProductSearchViewController: UINavigationController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var mainSearchView: MainSearchView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        applyTheme()
        setupNavigationBar()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    func applyTheme() {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(named: "appPrimaryColour")
        self.mainSearchView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    }
    
    func setupNavigationBar() {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString("product.search.tab.bar.item.title", comment: "")
        self.navigationBar.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Custom View:

```
import UIKit

class MainSearchView: UIView {
    
    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UITextField!
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() {
        let xib = UINib(nibName: "MainSearchView", bundle: nil)
        xib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)
        addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.frame = self.bounds
        contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    }
}
```

Comment: Either you class and module is wrong please Check. in ProductSearchViewController storyboard

Comment: If you are really using the code you've shown... are you getting the error on this line `self.mainSearchView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow`?

Comment: @DonMag yes, the code is stopping on this line although it is caused because the mainSearchView object is nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ProductSearchViewController is extended from UINavigationController, If it will get extended from UIViewController your problem will get solved.

Comment: This worked - Can you explain why? I wanted this screen to be a navigation view controller as it should be the root view controller for this section of the app

Comment: @Dylan, UINavigationController can't have subviews as it is a container of view controllers that defines a stack-based scheme for navigating hierarchical content.

Coming to your solution you can use following code

let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "YourStoryBoardName", bundle: nil)
let VC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProductSearchViewController") as! ProductSearchViewController
let navRootView = UINavigationController(rootViewController: VC)

Comment: Ah sorry okay I understand now. So I should just use that navigation view controller as my 'base', and then contain other VCs inside it and push and pop them as I see fit